# how to reset develop branch to master

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have `develop` & `master` branches, my `develop` branch is messy now and i would like to reset it and make it as a copy of my `master`. i'm not sure if merging the `master` into `develop` will make both of them identical. after trying to merge i got many conflicts i solved them using:

```
git checkout develop
git merge origin/master
//got many conflicts
git checkout . --theirs
```

is this enough for `develop` branch to be an identical copy to `master` ?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to [delete the branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)?

Comment: Setting `develop` as the new default branch (a few clicks with Github's web interface) is the most reversible solution.

Comment: what is preventing you of checking out a new branch from master?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

If you want to make `develop` be identical to `master`, the simplest way is just to recreate the pointer:

```
git branch -f develop master
```

Or, if you already have `develop` checked out:

```
git reset --hard master
```

Note however that both of these options will get rid of any history that `develop` had which wasn't in `master`. If that isn't okay, you could preserve it by instead creating a commit that mirrored `master`'s latest state:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-commit master
git checkout --theirs master .
git commit
```

Comment: my develop branch is used by other developers, so if i reset --hard how can i push that to other developers ?

Comment: @ra_htial They'd need to reset to it as well. You probably don't want to use the first two options if you're sharing the branch with others, unless they also know to reset and don't have any pending work.

Comment: Yes we all agreed to reset it, then we should all reset it and then start our work and push as usual ?

Comment: found myself in this unfortunate situation. I used the last solution, but it doesn't remove files that weren't in master. To do that I had to first do `git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=D develop master` to find the files, then remove them either one-by-one or by copying their paths into a file and running `cat file | xargs rm`

Comment: I tried the 3rd approach.  It worked like a charm except new files were not removed. I removed manually. Thanks @Amber

Comment: This one-liner cleans up removed files that were never in master: `git diff-tree -r --diff-filter=D development master --name-only | xargs git rm --ignore-unmatch`

Comment: This recipe worked like a charm! Brilliant! but ... subsequent merging only works for new feature branches. Old features branches will have weird conflicts

Comment: You should be doing what's in the next best answer, i.e. once on develop branch do:

`git reset --hard master`

Otherwise you get an error message

Comment: will we also overwrite develops upstream branch?

Answer (score 201):

If you want the two branches to be the same then

```
// from Develop and assuming your master is up to date with origin/master
git reset --hard master
```

Comment: This is the method that worked for me...otherwise you get a warning about paths can not be hard reset.

Comment: And if  `git push` fails and updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart, then `git push -f`.

Comment: And if you get something like: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/<your branch> You'll have to update/remove the Branch protection rules on github for that branch. github-->settings-->branches

Comment: Also, you can use the SHA of any commit to reset the branch to that state:
`git reset --hard <SHA>`

Comment: Is the reset recursive in nature? What will happen to child branch of the develop branch? And if the child branch won't get reset, will it's base branch change to master or will remain develop?

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails, you can delete your current branch and just directly recreate it from `master`.

```
git branch -D develop
git checkout master
git checkout -b develop
```

Comment: I tried this in web interface ran into two issues:
1. it really do not delete the branch and marks it archive
2. Once I did this in cmd interface it said my stage is diverged. Now every time I try stage builds i have to clone to a different location and checkout stage. which is very annoying

Answer (score 3):

For example making `staging` branch identical to `develop`, one could simply recreate the pointer:

First make sure your local develop branch is up to date with `origin/develop` by running:
`git checkout develop && git pull origin develop`

Then checkout your target branch (in this case `staging`)
`git checkout staging`

And finally but not least reset target branch
`git reset --hard develop`

Push changes by brute force (git will complain because local pointer have different address)
`git push -f`

And that would be pretty much it!

Answer (score 2):

### Reset Last Commit

```
git reset HEAD~
```

Comment: This assumes develop was branched out from master and is 1 commit ahead of master. The OP had a general question of "*i would like to reset it and make it as a copy of my `master`*".

Answer (score -3):

I'm a bit late to the party, however, after merging my dev branch into the master and pushing to the server, I do the following:

`git fetch`

`git checkout development`

`git merge origin/master`

`git push`

The the dev branch is one commit ahead of the master branch, and other developers don't have to worry about all commits in the development branch being reset.