# Is there a way to merge with Strategy "ours" without producing a new commit?

Tags: git, merge

What I need to do is close a branch and make the tip (last commit) of another branch looking like a merge with that branch without actually change its content. I tried

```
git merge -s ours other_branch --squash
```

but nothing happened (which made sense after I read [what squash actually does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787026/2598904))

I.E. before command

```
  * other_branch
 / 
*---* HEAD
```

expected result after command

```
  * other_branch
 / \
*---* HEAD
```

Note: by content here I mean committed stuff: metadata would change as the operation I want to achieve is actually adding one more parent to the commit; I'm aware this is changing history and would affect at least the shasum.

Comment: Can you add a diagram?  Perhaps a bad question, but can you tell us why a normal merge would not give the desired results?

Comment: The aim is not creating 2 identical commits

Comment: `git reset --soft $(git log --format=%B -n 1 | git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD^ -p other_branch)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PetSerAl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560351/is-there-a-way-to-merge-with-strategy-ours-without-producing-a-new-commit#comment84126815_48560351) has the (or "a", at least) command you can use to achieve what you want.  The only thing missing is an explanation as to *why:*

```
git reset --soft $(git log --format=%B -n 1 | \
    git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD^ -p other_branch)
```

works.  I'll get to that in a bit, but first...

#### A literal answer

The literal answer to your question as asked, though, is "no".  Since subject lines can be edited away, let me quote it:

> Is there a way to merge with Strategy “ours” without producing a new commit?

The word *merge*, in Git, can refer to two things: the act of merging, or the result of a previous act-of-merging.  The first of these is a verb, *to merge;* the second is an adjective, a *merge commit*, or even a noun, *a merge*.  A merge commit is a commit with two parents (or more, but we only really care about two).

Running `git merge --squash` tells Git to perform the merge—i.e., do the verb part—but at the end, when making a new commit, make an ordinary, non-merge commit, i.e., suppress the merge-as-adjective effect.<sup>1</sup>  The point of this is that when you have a series of commits, e.g., a "branch" in the sense that's *not* just "a name pointing to a specific commit" (see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))

Running `git merge -s ours` tells Git to perform a faked-up act of merging—that is, *prentend* to do merge-as-a-verb, but not really do anything—resulting in a merge-as-an-adjective/noun commit.  Since the verb form is gone, the only thing remaining is the after-effect.  This is why using `--squash` is useless here: you propose to eliminate both the verb *and* noun, and there's nothing left.

---

<sup>1</sup>For no particularly good reason, `git merge --squash` has the side effect of setting the `--no-commit` argument as well, so that you have to manually run `git commit` at the end.  Note that a real merge (that makes a merge commit) can also be run with `--no-commit`, making you run `git commit` manually as well; or it can stop due to conflicts, which you must resolve, making you finish the commit manually.  The latest versions of Git have added `git merge --continue` to make this feel less awkward, but it just runs `git commit`.

---

#### Git has `--amend` but it doesn't quite get us there

The diagram shows what you want—which, if Git supported it, might be spelled `git commit --amend --add-parent`, for instance—but doesn't produce the key insight, and in fact `git commit --amend` is a small, or perhaps huge, lie, as it doesn't *change* a commit, it just makes a *new* commit that uses an unusual parent hash.

The normal `git commit` process executes a bunch of steps as if they were done all at once, so that either they all finish correctly, or nothing happens (or seems to, at least).  The steps are:

1. Obtain the current commit's hash ID (`git rev-parse HEAD`).  Call this *P*: the existing `HEAD` will be the new commit's parent.  (If you're concluding a merge, `MERGE_HEAD` will also exist and `git commit` reads it to get additional parents.  That's just for finishing merges, though.)
2. Write the current index to make a `tree` object (`git write-tree`).  Call this *T*, the tree hash ID.  (This may or may not be the same tree as some previous commit.)
3. Obtain your name and email address and the current time as committer.  Normally, use these as author too (you can override them).
4. Obtain a commit message.
5. Write out a new commit with all of this information (`tree` *T*, `parent` *P*, `author` and `committer` as obtained in step 3, and commit message obtained in step 4.  The result is a new commit hash *C*.
6. Write the *new* hash *C* into the current branch name, so that `git rev-parse HEAD` now produces *C*.

Using `git commit --amend` changes the procedure right at step 1: instead of getting `HEAD` as the parent commit, Git *reads the current commit's parent hashes* (there may be more than one, if you're `--amend`-ing a merge), and uses those in step 5.

The effect is to shove the current commit aside:

```
...--o--o--*   <-- master (HEAD)
```

becomes:

```
          *   [the commit that was HEAD before]
         /
...--o--o--@   <-- master (HEAD)
```

What you want to get Git to do is a bit different.

#### Why (and how) the shell command works

Git's `commit-tree` command produces new commit objects.  It's like step 5 of the six-step commit sequence above.  But it hasn't made a tree, and it does not have precomputed parent commit hashes ready to go, so it takes those as command line arguments:

`git commit-tree tree-hash -p parent-hash-1 -p parent-hash-2`

in this case.  The *`tree-hash`* we want is, like `git merge -s ours`, the *same* tree that the current commit has.  We can name that tree using `HEAD^{tree}`, which is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  The two parent hashes we want start with the parent of the *current* commit.  (We can assume there's only one such parent.)  Again, gitrevisions syntax gives us a way to write this: we can use `parent^1`, or `parent~1`, or leave out the `1` from either of those expressions.  The other parent hash we want is the commit to which `other_branch` points, so we can just name that.  That gives us:

```
git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD^ -p other_branch
```

This command reads the commit *message* from its standard input.  If we want to retain the commit message from the current commit, we can extract it with `git log`: `--format=%B` tells `git log` to show *each* commit by printing its subject-and-body as text, and `-n 1` tells `git log` to show only *one* commit.  The first commit that `git log` shows is, by default, the `HEAD` commit.  So this gives us the:

```
git log --format=%B -n 1 |
```

part—we pipe this `git log`'s standard output to `git commit-tree`'s standard input.

What `git commit-tree` does after making the commit is to print its hash ID to its own standard output.  Hence if we just ran this pipeline by itself, we'd see the new commit hash printed, but we would not *store* it anywhere.  What we need to do is change the current branch name—whatever that is—to point to the new commit; and `git reset --soft commit-hash` will do that, hence:

```
git reset --soft $(...)
```

The `$(...)` construct is the last bit: the shell takes this to mean *run the given command, capturing its standard output, then treat that standard output text as command arguments to `git reset --soft`.*  Since there's only one output-word—the new commit's hash—this runs `git reset --soft` on the new commit ID.

Comment: The first step also read `MERGE_HEAD` (if exists) to get other parents for merge commits.

Comment: @PetSerAl: right, I should probably include that in my list (or edit it in). BTW thanks for the typo edits, I was in a rush this morning...

Comment: thanks for excellent answer @torek! Tiny note for Windows users: apparently on "cmd" terminals, we need to type "^^" when "^" is mentioned in the answer

Comment: @62mkv: yes, I have read that in cmd.exe, `^` is the quoting character, kind of like ``\`` in sh/bash. I'm not sure this particular analogy is correct as I don't use Windows (and when I was forced to, I installed Cygwin, back in the late 00s).